# How can I set the 'start date' of model using a variable?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

How can I set the 'start date' using a variable, including both the date and time that came with it?

[image]

**What I have tried:**

```
getExperiment().getEngine().setStartDate(dateTypeVariable);
```

When I tried to initialize my variable "dateTypeVariable" with my other variables "date" and "time", which are of type int, I received an error message indicating that I cannot use an int value in the date variable.

I think the main issue is how to initialize the variable "dateTypeVariable" with a specific date and time of my choice.

Comment: Sorry, what? Read it several times and still don't understand :D Please clarify 2 things: What do you want to achieve? And what have you tried already. Many of your sentences just don't make sense, my friend. Very happy to help as usual, but please improve the quality :) (maybe try some AI tool to help you translate, sounds like a language issue more than anything)

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope that the problem is now much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply construct the `dateTypeVariable` variable correctly using the Date constructor, for example `Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min)`.

However, many of these are deprecated and you may want to define it differently, see [JavaDoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).